# How to change dojodatetimetextbox icon in XPages

Tags: xpages

I tried to replace Dojo DateTimeBox icon with a new One. The CSS does not work.
I use that CSS code But It does not work :(

[image: When I replace ıt looks like this]

```
  .dijitDateTextBox .dijitArrowButton .dijitArrowButtonInner 
    {
       background-image: url('calendar_32x32.png') !important;
    }



<xp:inputText id="eDate" value="#{document1.eDate}"  dojoType="dijit/form/DateTextBox">
    <xp:dateTimeHelper id="dateTimeHelper1">
    </xp:dateTimeHelper>
    <xp:this.converter>
    <xp:convertDateTime type="date" dateStyle="short">
    </xp:convertDateTime>
    </xp:this.converter>
    </xp:inputText>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the background image on the `dijitArrowButton` class you might get a better result.

Your CSS code would be:

```
  .dijitDateTextBox .dijitArrowButton .dijitArrowButtonInner 
    {
       background-image: none !important;
    }

 .dijitDateTextBox .dijitArrowButton {
    background-image: url('calendar_32x32.png') !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
 }
```